# Possible Learning Approach

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am working on a reinforcement learning problem where I have 8 different actions [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] and a symmetric state matrix of 10 by 10 (only upper or triangular matrix is sufficient). I know I could use a neural network to train my Q-function to learn best action for a current state. 
[image: State representation]

My question is how should I learn the best location in the upper matrix to take that action to get to the next state from the current state?